# Story with a child-like AI being used to control a fusion reactor by being taught that the plasma was broccoli and that it hated it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

The [recent news about AI controlling fusion](https://www.wired.com/story/deepmind-ai-nuclear-fusion/) reminded me of a story I read in the 1990s or early 2000s. It was probably in *Analog* magazine.

I think the story involved two scientists talking with a journalist about how they cracked the fusion problem. One group knew fusion worked but they couldn't design a program fast enough to keep up with the necessary calculations to keep the plasma centered in the reactor. The other group had a functional AI but it had the intelligence of a five year old child and was not very useful. They finally got the reactor to work by teaching the AI that the plasma was broccoli and it hated that vegetable. To keep from 'swallowing' it the AI had to keep the plasma centered and stable.

Comment: See also https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-04301-9 Degrave, J., Felici, F., Buchli, J. et al. Magnetic control of tokamak plasmas through deep reinforcement learning. Nature 602, 414–419 (2022). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-021-04301-9

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is "[The Broccoli Factor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47902)" (1990) by Timothy Zahn.

The story is pretty much as described, the major difference is that JUNIOR (the AI) is at a two-year-old level, not 5.

> "So what's the trouble this time?" Banning asked at last.
>
> "Oh, the usual," Hayes shrugged. "We can get the plasma hot enough, but **we can't figure out how to keep it confined long enough in the center of the vacuum chamber**.  Every time we reconfigure the fields to eliminate one instability - Blooie! - another one crops up, drives the plasma out to the wall, and that's that."
>
> "Computer design doesn't help?"
>
> "Not so far.  I don't suppose you've got JUNIOR to the point of understanding plasma physics yet?"
>
> "Don't rub it in," Banning growled.
>
> "Sorry," Hayes apologized.  "Still **stuck at the two-year-old intelligence level**, eh?"

Hayes figures out how to use JUNIOR:

> "Then kindly explain *that*," Banning demanded, waving at the fusion test chamber.  "JUNIOR can't possibly have the intelligence or expertise that demonstration showed."
>
> "Ah - but you underestimate two-year-olds," Hayes waggled a warning finger at him.  "**All I had to do was find the proper age-specific behavior pattern and figure out how to adapt it**."

And the final explanation:

> "That's right," Hayes nodded. "I tied JUNIOR into the test chamber... and then **programmed him to hate the taste of plasma**."

The story itself doesn't specifically mention broccoli, but it's called out in the title.

Answer (score 23):

This must surely be "[The Broccoli Factor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47902)" by Timothy Zahn, first published in *Analog* in 1990, and later published in *Star Song and Other Stories* in 2002. The plot essentially goes exactly as detailed in the question. An AI named JUNIOR has the intelligence of a two-year old, a typical example of which is aversion to eating broccoli. Luckily this is the perfect form of behavior to control a plasma so that it doesn't touch the walls of the containment chamber:

> What does a kid JUNIOR’S age do when you make him eat something he
> doesn’t like? He pushes it around with his teeth and the tip of his
> tongue, trying like the devil to swallow it without letting any of it
> touch the sides of his mouth.

Accordingly, the scientists connected JUNIOR to the fusion experiment, and programmed it to hate the taste of plasma.

The story is available for loan at the [Internet Library](https://archive.org/details/starsongothersto00timo/page/90/).